# How do I filter out the last current hour from oracle SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

fairly new to SQL and trying to build some simple queries to reduce my dependence on power query!
I have a report and need to only show the historical hours data, not including the current hour, in my final result. I've managed to build something that works, but cannot figure out how to remove the final hour! now this query might not be the shortest or most eloquent, but it works, so please bear with me :) and feel free to suggest any alternatives (I learn best by actually trying to do something)

```
SELECT 
lt."Date",
lt."day" "Day",
concat(lt."Integrated In", ':00') "Integrated In",
lt."Qty Ordered",
rt."Qty Ordered" "Sum Ordered",
round((lt."Qty Ordered"/rt."Qty Ordered")*100,2) "Percentage",
sum (lt."Qty Ordered") over (order by lt."Integrated In" rows unbounded preceding 
       ) "Rolling Total"
FROM 
(select
TRUNC(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London') as "Date",
extract(hour from  oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London') as "Integrated In",
to_char(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London', 'DAY') "day",
COUNT (ol.qty_ordered) as "Qty Ordered"
from order_header oh
full join order_line ol
on oh.order_id = ol.order_id
WHERE TRUNC(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London') = TO_DATE(SYSDATE)
AND oh.order_type IN ('UKDCSTDRM', 'UKDCEXPRM', 'UKDCPOPRM', 'UKDCAPRM', 'UKDCEXPUP', 'UKDCSTDUP', 'UKDCAPUPS', 'UKDCPOPUP')
Group By TRUNC(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'), to_char(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London', 'DAY'), extract(hour from  oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London')
Order By to_char(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London', 'DAY'), extract(hour from  oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London')) lt

full join 

(select 
to_char(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London', 'DAY') "day",
SUM (ol.qty_ordered) as "Qty Ordered"
from order_header oh
full join order_line ol
on oh.order_id = ol.order_id
WHERE TRUNC(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London') = TO_DATE(SYSDATE)
AND oh.order_type IN ('UKDCSTDRM', 'UKDCEXPRM', 'UKDCPOPRM', 'UKDCAPRM', 'UKDCEXPUP', 'UKDCSTDUP', 'UKDCAPUPS', 'UKDCPOPUP')
Group by to_char(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London', 'DAY')
Order By to_char(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London', 'DAY')) rt 

on lt."day" = rt."day"
```

So I'm at a loss, I know I can truncate a date down to an hour, but everywhere I try the code, it either doesn't filter at all, or filters everything!

This is the code

```
WHERE TRUNC(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London') < TRUNC(TO_DATE(SYSDATE),'HH')
```

Current end result looks like this, but the result needs to omit the final hour (10:00 in the below example)

[current final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4P1j.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Try `where oh.creation_date < trunc(sysdate, 'hh')` as you probably don't want to set CREATION_DATE to *midnight*, and you don't apply TO_DATE on SYSDATE (which is a function that already returns DATE datatype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without some sample data and the expected output for that sample data it is difficult to test your code. However, you appear to want to:

- Filter the data to only today's data (in the London time zone)
- Generate a `COUNT` per hour
- Generate a total of the `COUNT` per day (although you are using `SUM` rather than `COUNT`, is that a mistake?)
- Filter the aggregated counts to exclude the current hour.
- Display the date, day, hour, quantity-per-hour, total-quantity for the day, percentage and a cumulative total quantity.

You can do that (and eliminate the `FULL JOIN`) using:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(creation_hour) AS "Date",
       TO_CHAR(creation_hour, 'FMDAY') AS day,
       TO_CHAR(creation_hour, 'HH24:MI') AS "Integrated In",
       qty_ordered_hour,
       total_ordered_day,
       ROUND(qty_ordered_hour/total_ordered_day*100, 2) AS percentage,
       SUM(qty_ordered_hour) OVER (ORDER BY creation_hour) AS rolling_total
FROM   (
  SELECT TRUNC(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London', 'HH24') AS creation_hour,
         COUNT(ol.qty_ordered) as qty_ordered_hour,
         SUM(COUNT(ol.qty_ordered)) OVER () AS total_ordered_day
  FROM   order_header oh
         FULL OUTER JOIN order_line ol
         ON oh.order_id = ol.order_id
  WHERE  TRUNC(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London')
           = TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE  'Europe/London')
  AND    oh.order_type IN ('UKDCSTDRM', 'UKDCEXPRM', 'UKDCPOPRM', 'UKDCAPRM', 'UKDCEXPUP', 'UKDCSTDUP', 'UKDCAPUPS', 'UKDCPOPUP')
  GROUP BY 
         TRUNC(oh.creation_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London', 'HH24')
)
WHERE  creation_hour < TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE  'Europe/London', 'HH')
```

If you don't want to include the current hour's values in the daily total then move the final `WHERE` filter into the sub-query.

Comment: Thanks MT0!!!, This works and is much shorter than mine :) I've moved the final "WHERE" into the subquery so the totals match (this would have just caused confusion otherwise!) I'm going to spend some time reviewing this compared to mine, hopefully it will help me be a little better.